# MS Edge - window.print() is not frame contextual in MS edge

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, printing, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge is not handling window.print() consistently when compared with other browsers.

In most browsers calling window.print() from within an iframe on a page will only print the contents of that iframe. However in edge it will always print the whole document.

Was this intentional? Is there workaround?

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw827m38/).

iframe.html

```
...
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print()">print iframe document</a>
</body>
...
```

index.html

```
...
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print()">print outer document</a>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
...
```

Comment: Nothing indicates it should be changed http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#printing probably a bug or oversight.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [confirmed issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1589775) with microsoft, quote:

```
Posted by Microsoft on 7/29/2015 at 12:46 AM
We were able to confirm the issue, and will be working to resolve it in a future release
```

No workaround exists yet.

Answer (score 4):

We fount a magic solution:

```
parent.document.getElementsByName("pdfjs-frame")[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);
```

...works in IE, EDGE, Chrome. The other was not tested yet.

Comment: Where do you run this code and how? and what happens if you have multiple PDF iframe's open? (when i just execute this code i get `Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference`).

Comment: @tchelidze We have iframe with src and it it works, exacly this line of code. Just tested in IE and Chrome.

@Peter Hi, sorry for late answer. First part of code is 
`parent.document.getElementsByName("pdfjs-frame")`
It should find the i frame in whole document by name attribute. So in this example it will find <iframe name='pdfjs-frame'>...

Comment: @prespic hmm, interesting, could you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506664/unable-to-print-pdf-file-in-edge-browser)

Comment: @tchelidze It is about authorization, nothing common with this problem. I cant help you with this, sorry.

Comment: I am getting "Permission denied" error. This works in IE, but not in Edge.

Comment: Just tested in EDGE, works fine. Simply put the line in console. Maybe it depends what iframe are you printing. We use it with [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Answer (score -1):

Its in IE too. You can fix it like this.

```
window.top.document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow.focus();
window.top.document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow.print();
```

It is tested. ;)