# Microsoft Edge Browser and Printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, microsoft-edge

I have a printUrl javascript/jquery function that loads a print friendly version of my web page into an iFrame and prints it.  It seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, and IE but I can't get it to work in Microsoft Edge browser.  The print dialog comes up but with the message "Nothing sent to print" in red.  Any help would be appreciated.  Function below:

```js
function printUrl(url) {
$('body').append('<iframe width="1" height="1" id="printFrame" style="display: none; @media print { display: block; }"/>');
$('#printFrame').attr('src', url);
$('#printFrame').load(function() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("Trident"); // detect if IE

    if (msie > 0) {

        var target = document.getElementById('printFrame');
        try {
            target.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
        } catch (e) {
            target.contentWindow.print();
        }
    } else {
        // this code executes for Edge printing as well as Chrome, Firefox  
        var frame = document.getElementById('printFrame');
        if (!frame) {
            $.alert("Error: Can't find printing frame.");
            return;
        }
        frame = frame.contentWindow;
        frame.focus();
        frame.print();
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#printFrame').remove()
    }, 500);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue, and already posted in MS Connect website [[Edge] Printing iframe window ends up printing top window](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1589775)

Answer (score 0):

We found this solution:

```
parent.document.getElementsByName("pdfjs-frame")[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);
```

[posted here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39790260/984081)